# React Native - Bring bottom image to top layer

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, css-position, react-native-stylesheet

I have a custom design that looks like this:

[image]

And I want to have the "X" mark layered on top of the three stripes. When I do position absolute it works but only works for the  that it is contained in /it get's cut off. How can I layer the "X" on top of all of the 's below?

```
    <View style={styles.lightGrey}>
      <View style={styles.red}>
        <View style={styles.yellow}>
          <View style={styles.teal}>
            {!preview && (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={async () => {
                  setIsLoadingDISLiked(true);
                  await onDisliked();
                  setIsLoadingDISLiked(false);
                }}
              >
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="close-thick"
                  size={34}
                  color="black"
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: Constant.width * 0.65,
                    marginTop: Constant.height * 0.01,
                    position: "absolute",
                  }}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          </View>
```

styling

```
  red: {
    height: Constant.height * 0.08,
    width: Constant.width,
    backgroundColor: Colors.Brick,
  },
  yellow: {
    height: Constant.height * 0.08,
    width: Constant.width * 0.75,
    backgroundColor: Colors.LightMustardYellow,
  },
  teal: {
    height: Constant.height * 0.08,
    width: Constant.width * 0.7,
    backgroundColor: Colors.Teal,
  },
  lightGrey: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.LightLightGrey,
    paddingBottom: 100,
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use z-index ('zIndex' in react-native) to choose which element goes on what layer you want. css guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score 0):

you can put x icon under main view container as **last item** with `position : 'absolute'`

your code may be something like this see this code in [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@ahmed_gaber/position-absoulte-x-icon)

```js
<View style={{flex : 1}}>

        <View style={{backgroundColor : '#ddd', height : 100}}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor : '#bbb', flex : 1, margin : 20}}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor : '#999', flex : 1, margin : 20}}>
                    <View style={{backgroundColor : '#666', flex : 1, margin : 20}}>

                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>

        //put icon x here at last item in main container
        <View style={{
            position : 'absolute',
            top : 10, right : 10, height : 30,
            width : 30,
            backgroundColor : '#f00',
        }}>
            <Text style={{color : '#fff', alignSelf : "center", fontSize : 20}}>x</Text>
        </View>

    </View>
```

and this the result
[image]